# Determine $\int_C F\cdot dx$ where $F(x,y,z)=(z,-y,x)$ and $C$ is the line segment from $(5,0,2)$ to $(5,3,4)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So first thing I did was parametrize the line. I used $\gamma(t)=(5,t,2+\frac{2}{3}t)$ For $t\in [0,3]$

I then have $F(\gamma(t))=(2+\frac{2}{3}t,-t,5)$

and $\dot\gamma(t)=(0,1,\frac{2}{3})$

Then $\int_C Fdx=\int_0^3 \langle F,T\rangle=\int_0^3 -t+\frac{10}{3}dt=-\frac{2}{3}$

I'm pretty sure my parametrization is incorrect as I dont think I should get this negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct; except the last step of the integration, which is $$\int_0^3\left(\frac{10}{3}-t\right)\mathrm dt=\frac{11}{2}.$$